# Stuck authenticating with Audiomack's API

Tags: python, oauth, api-authorization

Audiomack's API docs doesnt make sense to me. They say

"Rather than manually creating code for OAuth, we recommend instead using one of the pre-built libraries available for your programming language."

This is their API documentation.

https://www.audiomack.com/data-api/docs

I'm used to signing in to an API and getting a client secret/token/something.
there are many oAuth libraries (https://oauth.net/1/#:%7E:text=Max%20Countryman%20maintains,Tornado%20Auth%20package )
and all of them still require client secret, token and other authentication params.

Tldr; where do i get my auth tokens to Audiomacks API?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this ?

Comment: You can reach out to them for API stuff here https://audiomack.com/contact-us/api

Comment: anyluck, the contact-us/api has a validation that clears the company and otheer fields once you select a category